# Calling OpenOffice spell/grammar check from a C/C++ program

Tags: c++, c, spell-checking, openoffice.org

The problem is as follows: I'm writing a brute-force decrypter to crack some supersecret code (it's a contest, not a crime), which turned out to be impossible: just too many nodes in the tree that needs to be searched. To overcome this problem, I thought it might be helpful to check the intermediate 'solutions' to see if they produce (parts of) sentences. For example, I might get something like: "jvabaosajbgasgav..." or "lookslikeitsworking....". The first clearly is gibberish and in that case it wouldn't make any sense to continue cracking the code. The second one can easily be identified by eye as a valid English sentence.

I'm not planning on writing my own spell/grammar checker, so I thought it might be possible to call the spell checker from an open source project like OpenOffice or LibreOffice. I checked the openoffice.org website but I couldn't really find out what to do next. Like, how can I link against their libraries? Are these libraries in the SDK? What functions can I use?

The program I'm writing is in pure C, so I probably need to write a wrapper to call their C++ member-functions, right?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Not really a direct answer to your question, but wouldn't it be better to perform some kind of statistical analysis on the output, rather than a full spell/grammar check? Written text generally has strong patterns in terms of frequencies for different characters, character pairings, etc.

Comment: That's correct, but my guess is that my intermediate output will typically be very short, so these statistical tricks won't be very helpful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'd be vastly more successful integrating with something written with such integration in mind, like the [Aspell library](http://aspell.net/).

Comment: Cool! I feel kinda stupid now for not having thought of this myself. Thanks!